# Real TIme Database Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime database, for my flutter project. I am curious about the storage which is limited to 1GB, I want to know how the used up storage appears, say for example if I store 1mb data it would show me 1mb storage occupied of GB storage, soo if I delete the 1MB data from the RTDB will it show 0MB used in 1Gb storage or it'll show 1MB because I already used it previously. I know this is a simple question, I just want to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage limit is what u store not what u read/write. So if u remove 1mb u have 1 GB to use.

For more info

Firebase bills for the data you store in your database and all outbound network traffic at the session layer (layer 5) of the OSI model. Storage is billed at $5 for each GB/month, evaluated daily. Outbound traffic includes connection and encryption overhead from all database operations and data downloaded through database reads. Both database reads and writes can lead to connection costs on your bill. All traffic to and from your database, including operations denied by security rules, leads to billable costs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing